# Initialising State in React Redux app with data in server

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on my first React Redux project.

The project depends on a server to get its data and therefore there is also a server API that needs to be called in order to get those data.

My question is about initialising state.

There are 2 ways I can think of initialising state:

1.) First pass an empty object `{}` as the initialised state of the Redux store then inside `componentDidMount` that is where I call the API to access the data in the server and then update the state of the store/app then.

2.) In the reducer of the Redux app call all relevant server method (e.g. `getCategories()`, `getPosts()`, etc.) then compose a object with all of the data e.g. {categories: categories, posts: posts} then pass this object to the reducer as the initial state.

Which way is the recommended way for Redux when dealing with data stored in the server?
If there is a 3rd or 4th way that is the Redux way or the recommended way then please share your knowledge.  Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend the 1st way as you can handle the errors and show the user the specific error accordingly. And instead of 'componentDidMount' you can use 'componentWillMount'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is the better way of initializing state. Your component makes the necessary API calls in `componentDidMount` and passes the data to Redux as payload of `actions` which the `reducers` use to update the `state` of your application.

The second way is not advisable. According to the Redux [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html):

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state.
>
> `(previousState, action) => newState`
>
> ...
>   It's very important that the reducer stays pure. Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> 1. Mutate its arguments;
> 2. **Perform side effects like API calls** and routing transitions;
> 3. Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

**Edit**: 
You can also use `thunk` middleware and `async` actions to do API calls as explained in the Redux [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) and @DiegoTArg's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The way I work with data coming from the back end, and as far as I know is also the suggested way, is this:

- In the componentDidMount method call a thunk action creator. you can read more about them in [this](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) link.
- Inside that thunk action creator you first dispatch a REQUEST action, then perform a fetch to access the back end and when the response arrives you handle it on either the success or error handlers. Depending on the handler executed you dispatch either a SUCCESS or an ERROR action (and you attach to it all the relevant information that is coming from the back end so the reducer can access it).
- In your reducer you write code to handle all the above actions (REQUEST, SUCCESS and ERROR). Each handler will transition your state, for instance the REQUEST can set an isFetching flag to true that will let you show a spinner in the UI, and the SUCCESS can set that flag to false and populate the state with the data coming from the back end and passed to the reducer using the action dispatched.
- Once your reducer is updated, you will access that updated state from the UI, for instance using the connect react-redux function.

Regarding the initial state, it should represent a default state. for instance, it will have the isFetching flag in false and, if you are fetching a list of foods from the back end, then that list could be an empty list in your initial state. This is just a for instance of course. You need to set an initial state that makes sense to your app.

I hope this helps you.